# SKPaymentQueue Transaction issues iOS

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

I have been testing In App Purchases and can only assume that there are transactions stuck in the queue.

I have called `[[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] finishTransaction:transaction];` but every time I start the app it asks me to login to iTunes.

I have checked within `-(void)paymentQueue:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue updatedTransactions:(NSArray *)transactions{` but even if I place an NSLog in the first line, this is NOT being called. Thus I don't believe this is being called.

I have also called `NSLog(@"PAYMENTQUEUE:%@",[[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] transactions]);` which shows null.

Can someone advise why I would constantly be asked to login to iTunes every time I start the app all of a sudden? As I say, I can only assume it is a transaction, but how can I track it down?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just in case anyone comes across this later on with the same issue. I left the device and stopped trying to sort it out. I deleted the app too.

Around half an hour later I was prompted to logon to the iTunes sandbox store (remember there was no app on anymore).

I logged in, and this scenario occurred another time.

After that all seemed to go quiet.

I have tried installing the app again today (12 hours later) and the issue has gone away.

I can only assume something got jammed up?

Answer (score 1):

Your device has been infected with the "endless loop" for failing to have called finishTransaction.  It will reoccur every week like clockwork.  Check out the IAP Developer's Forum for more info.  The queue is empty because you need to log in as the 'infected' user.

Comment: Hi! I actually had it occur again, and when I looked and ran `NSLog(@"PAYMENTQUEUE:%@",[[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] transactions]);` I could see the transactions. It turned out they were 'Failed' transactions, and I needed to add `SKPaymentTransactionStateFailed:` and then Finish the transactions, then they disappeared, and I haven't had a prompt since. May be worth a check for people?